# Jquery change class on click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have those codes that i use on click to change classes

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.add").click(function(e){
    $.ajax({url: "?action=add&postid=" + $(this).parents('div.box').first().attr("id")})
    $(this).removeClass('add').addClass('remove');
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.remove").click(function(e){
    $.ajax({url: "?action=remove&postid=" + $(this).parents('div.box').first().attr("id")})
    $(this).removeClass('remove').addClass('add');
    });
});
```

When i click first time the div class changes from `<div class="add">` to `<div class="remove">` and the ajax url works, but when i click again from the changed class nothing happens. ( it doesn't change back to add class )

Comment: Did you try using "on('click', function(){})" instead of "click(function())" ?

Comment: I've tried now and still not working.

Comment: This wouldn't make a difference. Both syntax are correct .click and .on( "click" )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element that you want to listen for events to do not exist yet when you attach the event handlers, it is better to attach the event handlers using the `.on` method. In your case, you can do it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add', function() { ... });
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() { ... });
```

This is called **event delegation**, which (in my own understanding) attaches event handlers to an element up above in the DOM tree which is sure to exist once the page loads. Events will bubble up the DOM tree (unless prevented), executing all the event handlers in the elements that they pass by.

Answer (score 1):

Probably that's because on document ready event there is no `div` element with class of `remove`, so your `$("div.remove")` returns an empty collection. One option for solving the issue is using the event delegation technique:

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.remove', function() {
    // ...
});
```

But in this case I suggest using the `hasClass` and `toggleClass` methods for toggling and checking the class names:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.add").click(function(e) {
       var add = $(this).toggleClass('add remove').hasClass('add'),
           id = $(this).closest('div.box').attr("id"),
           action = add ? 'add' : 'remove',
           url = '...';

       $.ajax({
          url: url
       })
    });
});
```